# Реализация альтернативного ToolTip

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет.
Есть необходимость сделать альтернативную версию `ToolTip`. Выбрал `WebBrowser` на второй форме. Задача такая при наведении на `Textbox` в `form1` должна появляться `Form2`,на которой и есть тот самой `WebBrowser`.Но проблема в том что при перемещении мышки на `Textbox` в `Form1`, `Form2` должна следовать за ним. Но тогда `Form1` начинает мигать при каждом появлении `Form2`. Как сделать так чтобы `Form1` не мигала при появлении `Form2`?

```
Form2 form2;
private void Texbox1_MouseEnter_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
form2 = new form2();
form2.show(Texbox1); 
} 
private void Texbox1_MouseLeave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f2.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно писать большой текст с разными цветами.Вот к примеру-^ffffffОграничение: Мужской
^ffffffМин. уровень: 10
^ffcb4aПостоянная одежда
^00ffffЦвет: Случайный.
^00ffffДля покраски нужно красителя: 1 Оно в себе включает цвета Html.Можно конечно преобразовать в обычный цвет но tooltip не поддерживает 1)Разные цвета 2)Динамический переход на новую строку.

Comment: А готовый компонент смотрели?

Comment: @BlackWitcher, если Вы про `System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip`, то я предложил его автору, но ему нужна именно форма, так как там много всякой *всячины*

Comment: Нет, я как раз про сторонние замены стандартного тул-типа. Задачка ведь такая, что не думаю, что у автора вопроса она у первого возникла.

Comment: В готовой программе при наведение на Textbox отображается так :http://s018.radikal.ru/i516/1611/36/faeb714372c4.png

Comment: Это не моя программа.Просто взята с интернета.

Comment: Или вот как в моей программе.Текст с Textbox преобразуется и показывается уже в richbox.http://s011.radikal.ru/i317/1611/e0/7008899aad77.png

 Нужен такой же результат,либо в richbox или webbrowser на другой форме либо tooltip.Автор программы сказал что это Webbrowser на другой форме.

Comment: Да я знаю что он не следует.Код Mousemove делал но тогда вообще ужас.Форма мигает каждую миллисекунду.Прошу обратить внимание на первый скрин.Автор этой программы сказал что реализация -Webbrowser на другой форме

Comment: Потому что по сути там сделана перерисовка формы, и, подозреваю, раз мигает, то как-то не оптимально она сделана. Может быть, если у формы, на которой лежит браузер, выставить свойство `DoubleBuffered` в `true`, то будет лучше?

Comment: Так же.На первом скрине программа. При MouseMove textbox-а,и появлении form2,form1 никак не реагирует.

Comment: Посмотрите вот это, может, подойдет? [Раз](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9598/OverLibWrapper-C-wrapper-of-the-overLIB-DHTML-popu), [Два](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13321/Notes-Icon-Tooltip),

Comment: Оба приложения формируют Dll.Не совсем удобно тем более для шары.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно каждый раз создавать (`new`) и уничтожать (`Close`) форму - это слишком накладно. Создайте вторую форму один раз (например, в конструкторе основной формы) и показывайте-скрывайте в нужные моменты.

Для этого задайте текстбоксу следующие обработчики событий:

```
private void TextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    form2.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X + 5, MousePosition.Y);
}

private void TextBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (form2.Visible)
        return;

    form2.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X + 5, MousePosition.Y);

    // Здесь задавайте данные на этой форме-тултипе

    form2.Show(this);
}

private void TextBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox.ClientRectangle.Contains(textBox.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
        form2.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X + 5, MousePosition.Y);
    else
        form2.Hide();
}
```

Правда, здесь есть недостаток: если основная форма деактивируется при показанной форме-тултипе (например, нажать Atl+Tab или выскочит окошко другого приложения), то наш тултип не скроется. Думаю, это не страшно: достаточно двинуть мышкой на текстбоксе.

Для устранения этого недочёта можно применить таймер, но это тоже как-то не комильфо.

---

Вообще, использовать форму в качестве тултипа - слишком тяжеловесно. К тому же, именно из-за способности форм (де)активироваться возникает проблема корректного показа обеих.

Достаточно взять `Panel` (или любой другой компонент-контейнер), на неё поместить всё необоходимое (`WebBrowser` или `RichTextBox`). Изначально этой панели задайте свойство `Visible = false` (скрыта). Родителем панели должна быть сама основная форма (`Parent = this`). Эту панель нужно разместить перед всеми другими, поэтому вызовите для неё метод `panel.BringToFront();`

Код в обработчиках событий почти тот же:

```
private void TextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var point = textBox.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    panel.Location = new Point(point.X + 5, point.Y);
}

private void TextBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel.Visible)
        return;
    var point = textBox.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    panel.Location = new Point(point.X + 5, point.Y);
    panel.Show();
}

private void TextBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox.ClientRectangle.Contains(textBox.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
    {
        var point = textBox.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        panel.Location = new Point(point.X + 5, point.Y);
    }
    else
        panel.Hide();
}
```

И ещё нужно добавить обработку события деактивации основной формы:

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel.Hide();
}
```

Наша панель-тултип будет корректно скрываться.

Comment: Большое спасибо.Работает.Думаю не только мне это будет полезно.

Comment: Про panel1 заметил только щас.Сделал как написано но panel передвигается отрывками.

Comment: И кстати вот https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-r9JvxCC_s .Это то что я хочу сделать.Но как видно на видео это не контейнер ибо он не может выходить за форму.

Comment: Прошло много времени,автор программы выше подсказал что на второй форме использовался ShowWithOutActivation.Всем спасибо за ответы.